# Ladybug: Number of spots

Tags: species-identification, entomology, species

I'm interested in Ladybugs. I read a lot about the number of spots of ladybugs. The number seems to be between 0 and 24, but as far as I can see, not every number in between exist. Up to now, I found ladybugs species with 0, 2, 4, 5, 7, 10, 11, 13, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19, 22 and 24 spots. Do more exist? Is there a scientifique site in the net with exactly that subject?

Thanks for your answers!

Ladybug